# Error when assigning value to a list

Tags: r

```
x <- list()
x[1] <- 1
x[2] <- 1:10
```

A list can contain any type of data structure, so why am I getting a warning message?

```
In x[2] <- 1:10 :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: This is documented in `?Extract`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you're attempting to replace one NULL list element with a length 10 vector.

```
> x <- list()
> x[2] <- 1:10  ## error, but x[2] <- list(1:10) works
## interestingly, you did replace the first value
> x[[2]]
## [1] 1
```

---

Double brackets can be avoided on occasion, like if you fill all the empty `list` elements at once, operating on a vector of indices (e.g. `x[1:2]`).

```
> x <- vector('list', 2)
> x[1:2] <- list(1, 1:10)
> x
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

And the second element can be accessed with single brackets

```
> x[2]
# [[1]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use double brackets to access the elements of a list:

```
x[[1]] <- 1
x[[2]] <- 1:10
```

`x[2]` is not a member of the list `x`, but another list

```
> x[2]
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```